# Need help debugging, new to programming

Tags: java, debugging

Working on this code and cant debug it, have any ideas what its supposed to do is written in comment. thanks anyone who answers quickly. Any help will be great.

```
/*
        Debugging:  Speed
        When corrected, this program accepts an int value for starting mileage, an int value for ending mileage, a double value for time of travel, and then performs the calcualtion necessary to output the miles per hour.   The program should exit (quit) after the last window is closed.
    */

    public class Speed
    {
        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            //Declare Class Variables
            String highway;
            int startMiles=0;
            double endMiles=0;
            double time= 0;
            boolean done = false;

            while (done)
            {
                try
                {
                    String start = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter starting mileage: " );
                    startMiles = Integer.parseInt(start);

                    String end =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter ending mileage: " );
                    endMiles = Integer.parseInt(end);

                    if (endMiles<=startMiles) throw new Exception();

                    String amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter total time as a decimal value: " );
                    gallons = Integer.parseInt(amount);
                    done = true;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your ending mileage,",endMiles +", must be greater than your starting mileage, " + startMiles, "Error in Mileage", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Average speed is "+ (endMiles - startMiles)/time +"miles per hour.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Eclipse? IntelliJ? NetBeans?

Comment: look carefully at all the variables and their declarations.

Comment: using sublime, no debugger

Comment: if the name of the assignment is debugging perhaps you should use one?

Comment: thanks to anyone who is helping, i debuged much if it already then got stuck, posted where i was when i got stuck.

Comment: Please do the homework yourself or ask your teacher for further assistance. Voting to close.

Comment: What exactly does not work? You just told us that you're not able debug an unknown problem...

Comment: Repeating a comment-question from my answer below: I've never used a debugger, despite programming some moderately complicated stuff over the years (be gentle!). Is a debugger a *first* choice in situations like this, when few `System.out`-s would make the (at least the never-starting while-loop) problem obvious?

Answer (score 4):

First step is to write a whole bunch of

```
System.out.println("1");
```

To narrow down where the problem is happening. It would also be helpful to print out the value of some important variables.

As alluded to in other answers, this:

```
boolean done = false;

System.out.println("1");

while(done)  {
   System.out.println("2");
   ...
}

System.out.println("3");
```

outputs this:

```
1
3
```

Which should be a pretty big clue.

Comment: Old School debugging still very useful...

Comment: I probably shouldn't say this on stackoverflow, but despite doing some moderately complicated stuff over the years, I've never used a debugger.

Comment: Is a debugger a *first* choice, even when some simple `Sys.out` statements might suffice? Serious question. (I repeated this question above, as a comment to the original post)

Comment: @aliteralmind If you are using an IDE and you can set breakpoints with a single click, then yes, it is a _first_ choice.

Comment: That makes sense. I program in TextPad, and use PhraseExpress for auto-completion. I'm going to read up on debuggers.

Comment: @aliteralmind I sill use this idiom a lot - despite loving my IDE (NetBeans) I will often do this and fall back to the debugger, as a second choice, or when the number of lines output starts getting large or occasionally I want to introspect the state of some of my more complex objects.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one issue.

```
   boolean done = false;

   while (done){
      -- As Done is false nothing in here will ever run.
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see that your program probably does not even run. The issue you are having is with your while loop

```
boolean done = false;

while (done){
    //.....code.....//
}
```

What happens is your while loop expects a "true" value in order to run. You are setting done to be false at the start, therefore the loop is not executed. You can fix this by doing this

```
boolean done = false;

while (!done){
    //....code....//
}
```

So what this does "!" is basically like saying "since you are not done doing this continue" when you are done do not enter this loop ever again, just forget about it" more or less ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also you're assigning stuff to gallons rather than time, and then as an effect you're dividing by 0

Answer (score 0):

I debugged your code it should work correctly now. 
Try it.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            //Declare Class Variables
            String highway;
            int startMiles=0;
            int endMiles=0;
            int time= 0;
            boolean done = true;
            while (done)
            {
                try
                {
                    String start = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter starting mileage: " );
                    startMiles = Integer.parseInt(start);

                    String end =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter ending mileage: " );
                    endMiles = Integer.parseInt(end);

                    if (endMiles<=startMiles) throw new Exception();

                    String amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter total time as a decimal value: " );
                    time = Integer.parseInt(amount);
                    done = false;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your ending mileage,"+endMiles +", must be greater than your starting mileage, " + startMiles, "Error in Mileage", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, startMiles);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Average speed is "+ (endMiles - startMiles)/time +"miles per hour.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.By dividing by zero (gallon) that is why it is giving "The average speed is **infinity** miles per hour"

In this statement there is a concatenation error ....... ,",endMiles +", 
it should be   ...... ,"+ endMiles +",

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your ending mileage,",endMiles +", must be greater than your starting mileage, " + startMiles, "Error in Mileage", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);